# Energy realized in fusion and electrons?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, fusion

I was doing this question about the energy released in a fusion reaction:

[image]

In the mark scheme it included the mass of the electrons (for part cii) on the left and just used the mass of protons for the H. Do the H in this case not contain electrons and if so why do we not include  them in the calculation but do the once on the left??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of whether and how to include electrons/positrons in mass-energy calculations is based on the difference between the entities involved in the reaction, and the entities for which masses can be determined. This becomes more complicated when there may be both orbital electrons and nuclear-sourced electrons/positrons involved.

Consider the last equation in the OP's question.  The physical process is clear:  four bare protons with a total charge of +4, fuse to form a single bare helium nucleus or alpa-particle (charge +2) , and two positrons (total charge +2) ("Bare" here means no orbital electrons)

Charge is conserved, as is mass-energy.  ***If you knew the rest masses of a proton, alpha-particle and positron***, you could just add up the two sides of the equation to find the "missing" mass and equate it to the energy liberated.

But most sources of isotope mass list the mass of the nucleus ***including*** the element's appropriate number of orbital electrons.  Suppose you used these tabulated values for the hydrogen and helium in this reaction.  Using the tabulated value for $_1H^1$ would mean that you incorrectly included the mass of four extra electrons on the left-hand side.  Using the tabulated value for $_2He^4$  would mean that you incorrectly included the mass of two extra electrons on the right-hand side.  So, to get the right answer, you would need to add the two positron masses on the RHS, and an additional two electron masses on the RHS to correct for the "wrong" electrons.

In the example above, the alpha mass seems to explicitly exclude the extra electrons.  The nature of the proton mass is not stated. Without this information, the need for "bookkeeping" electron masses cannot be determined.

Answer (score 0):

The question says "nuclei of hydrogen" ie. protons. In the middle of a star there isn't likely to be much atomic hydrogen around!

Comment: Do we normally include electrons or not??